# Gridview Freeze Pane header not freezing after page loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, gridview, sql-server-2012

**Browser - IE 9**

**Using the Latest Version of [Microsoft's AdventureWorks2012 sandbox database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) (AdventureWorks2012_Data.zip) for SQL related Data.**

I had to put this project on the backburner a few months ago due to various job interrupts and whatnot.  What I'm looking for is a GridView that when it loads has a frozen header while the enduser scrolls the large amounts of data.  Where I left off was a product that, upon first load would look good but when the data was scrolled the header I want frozen would scroll up along with the data.

Now the SQL Data is solid and performs as expected.  This is mainly a cosmetic challenge that I've been scratching my head over for a bit.  I've attempted to tweak every possible ASP/CSS/Javascript option that I know of with no success.

Here's what I've got so far code wise (no C# page behind leveraged at all):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="<path to>/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="<path to>/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
            var header = $("#GridView1").find("tr")[0];
            $("#HeaderDiv").append(header);
        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">



    .GridViewStyle
    {    
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:11px;
        background-color: White; 
    }

    .GridViewHeaderStyle
    {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:15px;
        background-color:#507CD1;
        color:black;
        height:40px;

    }


</style>

<br />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorks2012ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[LoginID],[OrganizationNode],[OrganizationLevel],[JobTitle],[BirthDate],[MaritalStatus],[Gender],[HireDate],[SalariedFlag],[VacationHours],[SickLeaveHours],[CurrentFlag],[rowguid],[ModifiedDate] FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [HumanResources].[Employee] SET SELECT [NationalIDNumber] = @NationalIDNumber,[LoginID] = @LoginID,[OrganizationNode] = @OrganizationNode,[OrganizationLevel] = @OrganizationLevel,[JobTitle] = @JobTitle,[BirthDate] = @BirthDate,[MaritalStatus] = @MaritalStatus,[Gender] = @Gender,[HireDate] = @HireDate,[SalariedFlag] = @SalariedFlag,[VacationHours] = @VacationHours,[SickLeaveHours] = @SickLeaveHours,[CurrentFlag] = @CurrentFlag,[rowguid] = @rowguid,[ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate WHERE [BusinessEntityID] = @BusinessEntityID">
<UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="NationalIDNumber" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LoginID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganizationNode" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganizationLevel" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BirthDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MaritalStatus" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HireDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SalariedFlag" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VacationHours" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SickLeaveHours" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CurrentFlag" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="rowguid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BusinessEntityID" />
</UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>


      <div>
        <%--Div contains the new header of the GridView--%>
        <div id="HeaderDiv">

        </div>

              <%--Wrapper Div which will scroll the GridView--%>
        <div id="DataDiv" style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid olive; width: 2000px; height: 300px;" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewStyle"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="BusinessEntityID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#507CD1" DataField="BusinessEntityID" HeaderText="Business Entity ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BusinessEntityID" InsertVisible="False" ShowHeader="False" >
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NationalIDNumber" HeaderText="National ID #" SortExpression="NationalIDNumber" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LoginID" HeaderText="Login ID" SortExpression="LoginID" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationNode" HeaderText="Organization Node" SortExpression="OrganizationNode" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationLevel" HeaderText="Organization Level" SortExpression="OrganizationLevel" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="JobTitle" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MaritalStatus" HeaderText="Marital Status" SortExpression="MaritalStatus" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="HireDate" ShowHeader="False" />






        <asp:BoundField DataField="SalariedFlag" HeaderText="Salaried Flag" SortExpression="SalariedFlag" ShowHeader="False" />



        <asp:BoundField DataField="VacationHours" HeaderText="Vacation Hours" SortExpression="VacationHours" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" ShowHeader="False" />



        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentFlag" HeaderText="Current Flag" SortExpression="CurrentFlag" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rowguid" HeaderText="Row Guid" SortExpression="rowguid" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="Modified Date" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" ShowHeader="False" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As much as I'd like a solution for this, I would like more to learn why this page isn't behaving as designed.  I know the solution may be something simple I overlooked but I'd like to learn the theory behind fixing it as well.

Here's the latest result with the suggestions from @afzalulh  The white space is a blank header without any sort of text at all.

[image: Blank Frozen Header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You should name the javascript function `Onscrollfnction()`.

**EDIT:**

1. You replace the HeaderDiv content with tr html.
2. You have to apply style to HeaderDiv.

Here's the script:

```
</style><script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Onscrollfnction() {
        var header = $("#GridView1").find('tr:first').html();
        $("#HeaderDiv").html(header);
        $("#HeaderDiv").addClass("GridViewHeaderStyle");
    }
</script>
```

Further improvements:

1. I would apply fixed width to GridView Columns and apply the widths
   to headers in the HeaderDiv column headers.
2. I would hide the GridView's header and display the HeaderDiv
   instead, to avoid the annoying transition in the beginning of
   scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the help but after trying this, it didn't fix anything.  Same result.

Comment: Probably you forgot to replace this`<path to>` with physical path of jquery. I have tested the code above before posting and I have used this path:`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried this and the freeze pane works as I want BUT all the header information is missing.  Where the column titles should be is just white blank space.  There's no text, no links, nothing.

Comment: I uploaded an image with what I'm seeing to the first post in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I got frustruated with trying to find a javascript solution so I found one that is CSS based and works perfectly.  For anyone who needs it moving forward, here's the article I referenced.

[Scrollable GridView With Fixed Headers Asp.Net](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/scrollable-gridview-fixed-headers-asp.html)