# CSS Frozen Header in Gridview scrolls upwards when mouse hovers over 'Edit' link

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, sql-server, gridview

Browser - IE 9

Using the latest version of [Microsoft's AdventureWorks2012 sandbox database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330)
(AdventureWorks2012_Data.zip) for SQL related data.

No C# page used behind the scenes

First off, there's zero problems with the SQL or how the SQL data in the GridView is presnted (aside from the Frozen Header)

I'm in the process of trying to determine why this Frozen header I have set up for a GridView embedded in a panel moves with a mouse scroll whenever the mouse either hovers over the header or over the 'Edit' links I have set up at the beginning and end of each row.

The behaviors are:

Scenario 1 - Mouse Hovers Over Edit link While Scrolling - When I have the mouse hovering over the 'Edit' link and scroll up or down with the mouse, the frozen header moves up with the mouse scroll.  However, if the mouse hovers in the data area of the GridView, the header stays frozen.  When I hover the mouse over the header then scroll up and down the header stays in place.  When I move the mouse off of the Frozen Header after the up and down scrolling the header either re appears at the top of the page or disappears altogether.  In the scenario of the header disappearing completely, hovering the mouse over the Edit link brings the header back into place.

Scenario 2 - Mouse Hovers Over Frozen Header While Scrolling - As one of the things I tried, I thought to switch the editing links to buttons to see if that would solve the issue.  Scrolling the GridView with the mouse hovered over the 'Edit' buttons have no effect on the header at all.  The header stays in place and works as described.  Scrolling with the mouse hovered in the data area and the Frozen Header in the paneled GridView stays frozen.  However, when I hover the mouse over the header then scroll up and down the header stays in place.  When I move the mouse off of the Frozen Header after the up and down scrolling the header either re appears at the top of the page or disappears altogether.

**Here's the code for Scenario 1.  If more code is needed, please let me know.**

CSS

```
.header-frozen
      {
       font-weight: bold;
       background-color: white;
       position: relative;
       visibility: visible;
      }
```

ASP.NET

```
<div >
            <asp:Panel  ID="Panel1"  Height="600px" Width="9000px" ScrollBars="Vertical" runat="server">



<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" Height="600px"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewStyle"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BusinessEntityID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#507CD1" DataField="BusinessEntityID" HeaderText="Business Entity ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BusinessEntityID" InsertVisible="False" ShowHeader="False" >
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NationalIDNumber" HeaderText="National ID #" SortExpression="NationalIDNumber" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LoginID" HeaderText="Login ID" SortExpression="LoginID" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationNode" HeaderText="Organization Node" SortExpression="OrganizationNode" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationLevel" HeaderText="Organization Level" SortExpression="OrganizationLevel" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="JobTitle" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MaritalStatus" HeaderText="Marital Status" SortExpression="MaritalStatus" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="HireDate" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SalariedFlag" HeaderText="Salaried Flag" SortExpression="SalariedFlag" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VacationHours" HeaderText="Vacation Hours" SortExpression="VacationHours" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentFlag" HeaderText="Current Flag" SortExpression="CurrentFlag" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rowguid" HeaderText="Row Guid" SortExpression="rowguid" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="Modified Date" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" ShowHeader="False" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"/>
    </Columns>
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="header-frozen" Height="60px" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>



    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorks2012ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[LoginID],[OrganizationNode],[OrganizationLevel],[JobTitle],[BirthDate],[MaritalStatus],[Gender],[HireDate],[SalariedFlag],[VacationHours],[SickLeaveHours],[CurrentFlag],[rowguid],[ModifiedDate] FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [HumanResources].[Employee] SET SELECT [NationalIDNumber] = @NationalIDNumber,[LoginID] = @LoginID,[OrganizationNode] = @OrganizationNode,[OrganizationLevel] = @OrganizationLevel,[JobTitle] = @JobTitle,[BirthDate] = @BirthDate,[MaritalStatus] = @MaritalStatus,[Gender] = @Gender,[HireDate] = @HireDate,[SalariedFlag] = @SalariedFlag,[VacationHours] = @VacationHours,[SickLeaveHours] = @SickLeaveHours,[CurrentFlag] = @CurrentFlag,[rowguid] = @rowguid,[ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate WHERE [BusinessEntityID] = @BusinessEntityID">
<UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="NationalIDNumber" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LoginID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganizationNode" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganizationLevel" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BirthDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MaritalStatus" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HireDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SalariedFlag" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VacationHours" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SickLeaveHours" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CurrentFlag" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="rowguid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BusinessEntityID" />
</UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
                </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

Samples of what I'm seeing:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, if this a CSS matter, HTML code(not source)  and CSS would be useful to get the picture of what you have done, Eventually tell us about doctype (renders in standard or quirk mode in IE?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following answer has not been tested but might help someone create a working response.**

The method you have used appears to be based on the following article:

http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/f1baaf4e-ae5a-46d6-b409-03e203ea98d9.aspx

The above article is also referenced by the following Question on the ASP.NET forums which also offers an alternative solution:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1213517.aspx?How+to+fix+the+gridview+header+while+scrolling

To summarize I believe the general working of how the fix was implemented is as follows:

1) Move the `GridView` into a container element (you appear to already have done this to an extent)

```
<div id="gridviewContainer" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow: scroll; width: 100%; height:350px">
    <asp:GridView  ...>
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="header-frozen" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

2) Define the position within the CSS using an expression

```
.header-frozen{
    position: relative;
    top: expression(gridviewContainer.scrollTop-5);
}
```

*You should note that the ID of the `asp:Panel` you have created will have a different ID to the CSS, this is the `ClientId` attribute of the `Panel` in Code Behind*

I'm sure there's an easier way, possibly making the container `position:relative` and the header `position:relative` or `position:absolute` so anyone coming up with something which doesn't require the container name including in the CSS is much more reusable.

Comment: Actually its based on [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969097/1825029) which doesn't seem to be there anymore.